# CheckBox in SAPUI5 xml view not shown as checked

Tags: checkbox, sapui5

I have placed a checkbox in my SAPUI5 xml view as follows:

```
<CheckBox checked="true" editable="false"/>
```

However, the checkbox is shown as **unchecked**. Looking at the reference, `"checked"` is a boolean field; I cannot see anything wrong in above code.

Reference:
https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/test-resources/sap/ui/commons/demokit/CheckBox.html#settings

What's the matter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[sap.ui.commons.CheckBox](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.commons.CheckBox.html#constructor) uses checked, editable and enabled

[sap.m.CheckBox](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.CheckBox.html#constructor) uses selected and enabled

```
<CheckBox text="{field}" selected="true" enabled="false" />
```

is it possible you are using sap.m.Checkbox